# Email error: Could not access file

Tags: emails, plugin-sproutforms

Using Sprout Forms in conjunction with Amazon S3. The file is being uploaded to the S3 source, however it fails to send when viewing the Craft log.

[error] [application] Email error: Could not access file: /home/me/me.example.com/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/8540.txt

It appears that the file 8540.txt (named differently) is stored on Amazon S3, but it does not exist in the runtime/assets/sources/ directory. Any idea why the files for images successfully send and are properly created in the runtime/assets/sources/ directory but any other file type i.e. pdf, doc, txt, the server does not create the file and the email fails to send because the file does not exist.

Is this a server configuration or a Craft configuration?